# Edit multi select input in react-admin for one-to-many or many-to-many relationship?

Tags: graphql, react-admin, hasura

What is the current "out-of-the-box" way for editing many-to-many relationships in react-admin?

More specifically, is there any way to SelectArrayInput or AutoCompleteArrayInput over a referenced table?

My first table is `stream`
[stream table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ri9i.png)

My second table is `subject`
[subject table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08fsA.png)

and the mapping table for them is `stream_subject`
[mapping table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v55B1.png)

and I have to display my form like this
[edit form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QztSd.png)

Currently, I am using reference array input for that but it's not working, my current code is like this:

```
<ReferenceManyField label='Subject' reference='stream_subject' target='stream_id'>
    <ReferenceArrayInput label='Subject' reference='subject' source='subject_id'>
        <SelectArrayInput source='name'>
            <ChipField source='name' />
        </SelectArrayInput>
    </ReferenceArrayInput>
</ReferenceManyField>
```

Is there any way to create multi-select dropdown for this, I even tried using `useQuery` hook from react-admin but unable to make any progress even if anyone can help me out me `useQuery` methods can solve my problem.
For this I am using hasura-graphql datprovider: `https://github.com/Steams/ra-data-hasura-graphql`

My graphql is like this:
[graphql-query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jth4s.png)

Comment: You have find the solution ?

Comment: Not yet, but I think using custom query it can be done, I haven't tried it yet.